# Hard integral $\int_{0}^{e}n^{\operatorname{W^n(x)}}dx=?$

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals, exponentiation, lambert-w

It's a problem that I can sovle only for $n=2$ let me try it :

> > $$\int_{0}^{e}n^{\operatorname{W^n(x)}}dx=?$$
> >     Where $n\geq 2$ is a natural number and $\operatorname{W(x)}$ denotes the [Lambert's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) .
> >
> > ### The case $n=2$:
> >
> > $$\int_{}^{}2^{\operatorname{W^2(x)}}dx=\frac{1}{\log(256)}\Big(2^{-1 - \frac{8}{\log^2(16)}}\Big) \Big(e^\frac{1}{\log(16)}\Big) \Big(\sqrt{\frac{π}{\log(2)}} (\log(256) - 4) \operatorname{erfi}\Big(\frac{(\log(4) \operatorname{W(x)} + 1)}{(2 \sqrt{\log(2)})}\Big) + 8 \exp\Big( \operatorname{W(x)} + \log^2(4)  \frac{\operatorname{W(x)^2}}{\log(16)} + \frac{1}{\log(16)}\Big)\Big) + \operatorname{constant}
> > $$
> >     Where $\operatorname{erfi}$ denotes [the imaginary error function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html)

So in this case we have an antiderivative wich is relatively simple .

Unfortunately I can't find others antiderivatives of this kind for the others values of $n$.

### My question

Have you an idea to solve this ?

Thanks a lot and have fun .

Comment: The substitution $x=ye^y$ is obvious (to ease suffering for a moment).

Comment: I bet that this definite integral goes through a maximum value.